# Is it possible to make a constexpr tree?

Tags: c++, tree, constexpr

I would like to build a `constepxr` tree structure with a fixed number of children that may or may not be a Tree. The structure would be be able to answer the question "is there a node present at index 2 in this tree?"

Ideally I would like to write something like this:

```
  struct Tree {
   std::array<std::optional<Tree>, 5> children; // 5 children max for each tree
  };
```

Unfortunately `Tree` referencing to itself doesn't compile.

Is there something I missed, or a way to work around this limitation? Do you know an implementation solving a similar problem?

Comment: provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make an actual tree structure, as this requires memory allocations. Even in C++20 there are several limitations on it. However, as the content is fixed, you basically want a lookup structure on a sorted array. With std::array, std::sort and std::lower_bound you can do a lot. For small tree, you can even consider using a linear find as that's more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works on C++17. It should be possible but significantly more annoying on previous versions:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct no_node{};

template<class... ChildTrees>
struct Tree {
    using tuple_t = std::tuple<ChildTrees...>;
    tuple_t children;

    template<int N>
    static constexpr bool has_child() {
        if constexpr(N >= sizeof...(ChildTrees)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return !std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<N, tuple_t>, no_node>;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    Tree<> leaf;
    Tree<no_node, decltype(leaf)> right;
    static_assert(!leaf.has_child<0>());
    static_assert(right.has_child<1>());
    static_assert(!right.has_child<0>());
    static_assert(!right.has_child<2>());

}
```

Be warned that this generates a lot of types.

Comment: With deduction guides it's not too bad: https://godbolt.org/z/pqaTNN

Comment: I didn't just mean that it generates a lot of template arguments you have to type, but each node has its own type, so there will be a lot of types generated by the compiler. Nice code btw.